# Python task scheduler without threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

**Context**

I'm currently doing an API class based on `fastapi` which will be able to manage token access with access time.

**Objective**

I want to automatically remove token from the authorized tokens list when the access period comes to the end.

**How is it working**

I have a master token that can be used to generate a guest token at any time through a given path. A specific time also have to be provided to the API according to this format :

> API_URL/generate_token/MASTER_TOKEN/ACCESS_TIME

This is going to return a new guest token having as access periode the given "access_time" value.

When a guest token is created i register it and add a `Timer` from `threading` scheduled on the end of the access period which will remove the token from the registered ones.

**The issue(s)**

I don't want to create a new "thread" through the timer for each new guest token because i want the main thread to permanently have the priority. And i'm worried about the fact that if i have a lot of guest tokens the API will be slow a lot because of the priority swap of all that threads.

**Alternatives**

I thought about `sched` library. But this one present an issue that is all scheduled tasks have to be defined before we start the previously created sheduler with the line

```
scheduler.run()
```

And the problem is that a new guest token can be created and registered at any time. So i don't know how to deal with it properly.

Any help or research track will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having a Timer per token is sensible.

> Any help or research track will be appreciate.

Have a thread in charge of removing expired tokens, and otherwise sleeping it off? Depends how much precision you need there (`sleep` does not offer super precise wakeup guarantees).

On POSIX you could also use SIGALRM (`signal.alarm`), normally writing signal handlers is complicated but IIRC Python does its own thing.

Alternatively, just attach validity information to the token, and check that when a request comes in, possibly with a "reaping" once in a while (e.g. every hour or every day), whether that reaping would be a separate thread (on a timer or whatever) or just a hit on one of the requests.

Comment: I'll probably go for your last solution, that was what i was just thinking about, i'll check validity on each request and do a "garbage collector" thread which will remove periodically expired tokens. I already have the expiration date attached to each tokens so it will be easy to implement ! Thank you !